# increase the line width of rows and column of table in latex

Tags: tables

I want to increase the line width of some rows and columns of my tables. Here is my table. And in the figure, I've shown the part which I want to bold (for example the row and column around the cell "A" and etc).
Could you help me with that?

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{9698ED}\textbf{A}} & \textbf{b} & c          & d         \\ \hline
1                           & 2                          & 3          & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{n} \\ \hline
5                           & 1                          & 4          & 5          & 6         \\ \hline
7                           & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{d}                  & 8          & 9         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Please insert the table image in question! If you like to have bold text in some cells, enclose this text in `\textbf{<text in cell>}`. Also please provide complete small document, which reproduce your problem

Comment: Thanks @zarko. I don't want to bold the text in the cell. I have provided a mini example. Besides, I have provided a figure in the link in the question.

Comment: Link can become dead after while, also it is not simple accessible, so please copy image in question. Your example is very unclear (hasn't any contents in cells, what you than like to have bold?  Please edit your question and mike it more clear.

Comment: i think OP wants to increase line width of some cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccccc}[hvlines]
\Block[fill=[HTML]{9698ED},draw,line-width=1pt]{1-2}{A} & & b & c & d \\
1 & 2 & 3 & \Block[fill=yellow!15,draw,line-width=1pt]{1-2}{n} \\
5 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
7 & \Block[draw,line-width=1pt]{1-2}{d} & & 8 & 9 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you @F.pantigny